# Deployment changing the integration runtime of synapse and data factory artifacts to AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm running into a scenario when I run my deployment to different environments even though I have `SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime` specified on the linked services it auto resolves to `AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime`. How would I make it fixed to stick to `SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime`. I'm using Azure DevOps for our deployment.

***Linked Service:***

```
"connectVia": {
    "referenceName": "SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime",
    "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
}
```

Comment: Hello, make sure you have no problems with SHIR setup, and the status is green. What do you mean by running your deployment to different environments? Is this issue happening when you change something ?

Comment: Hi @ZiyaMertKarakas SHIR is setup and running no problem there.I'm not changing anything with respect to SHIR. Run my deployment in the sense, I make changes to the pipeline but nothing related to SHIR, I check-in my changes and run my deployment to DEV all the linked services are changed to use the `AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime`. I tried to exclude LinkedServices as part of deployment and run into errors no corresponding LinkedService found.

Comment: Let's say I go ahead with my deployment and manually switch the IntegrationRuntime to `SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime` run a few pipelines and say I've more changes to make in the copy activity settings I make these changes redeploy to development the LinkedServices are all set to `AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime` from `SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime` after the deployment. Not sure what might be causing this.

Comment: So are you using Git or Azure Devops ? 

If so, could this be happening because you did not publish your changes or commit to main branch, and the default saved values (in this case AutoResolve) come up ? Are you fully published?

Comment: Yes, all changes are checked into the main branch and fully published.

Comment: This is a problem with Azure Devops it seems. We are doing something wrong in the JSON templates (or we are overriding something) so it defaults to AzureIR.
Go through the templates of JSONs once again on azure devops side, and try to spot anything which might cause this. Unfortunately I cannot do much else from here, Azure Devops team needs to take a look. Try to raise a ticket with them if possible

Comment: Also can you please try disconnecting from AzureDevops, and changing the IR, then connecting back again?